# Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^2dx$

Tags: calculus

Partial integration gives

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^2dx=[-e^{-x}x^2]_{0}^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}xdx=[-e^{-x}x^2-e^{-x}x]+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx= \\ 
=[-e^{-x}x^2-e^{-x}x-e^{-x}]_{0}^{\infty}$$

For now, let $n$ be the upper bound, we have:

$$I_n=[-e^{-x}x^2-e^{-x}x-e^{-x}]_{0}^{n}=-e^{-n}(n^2+n+1)+1=\frac{-n^2-n-1}{e^n}+1$$

Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$ I get $I_n=1$. Answer is $2$. I can't find my screw-up.

Comment: you forgot your $2$ from your original question

Comment: in the first step of your integration by part you forgot that $(x^2)'=2x$

Comment: Also you've lost a 2 when differentiating $x^2$

Comment: The differentiation was the issue... thanks!

Comment: **Alternate approach:** Notice that the integral is just the Laplace transform of $f(t)=t^2$ with parameter $1$, which evaluates to $\dfrac{\Gamma(2+1)}{1^{2+1}}=\Gamma(3)=2!=2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual answer is 2. And I will provide some probabilistic view of this integral.

Set $X\sim ~Exp(1)$ so its pdf is $f(x)=exp(-x), x\geq0$.

Variance of X is given by

$$Var(X)= E(X^2) - E^2(X) = 1,$$

and

$$E(X)= 1. $$

So we have 
$$E(X^2) =2,$$
Which we are asked to find.

For other integrals of similar kind look at Gamma distribution. This example is also some kind of Gamma distribtion.

Comment: Answer is 2, not 4, I had a typo earlier, sorry. But thank you for this!

Comment: I have edited my answer so it can suit your question.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $x^2$ is not $x$, but $2x$. This is where you get 2.
The correct answer is

$$I=[-e^{-x}x^2-2e^{-x}x-2e^{-x}]_{0}^{\infty}=2$$